# ¿Como subir archivos ".zip" con php?

Tags: php, archivo, php5, fileupload

Utilizo esta librería para subir imágenes: [***piramideUploader***](https://github.com/victorobs/piramide-uploader).
Sube las imágenes sin problema, el problema es cuando intento subir un archivo ".zip".

Mi PHP es el siguiente:

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploads'])){
    $piramideUploader = new PiramideUploader();
    $upload = $piramideUploader->upload(
        'image', 
        "uploads", 
        "uploads", 
        array("image/jpeg","image/png","image/gif")
    );
    $file = $piramideUploader->getInfoFile();
    $file_name = $file['complete_name'];
    if(isset($upload) && $upload["uploaded"] == false){
        $result = array(
            'status'    => 'error',
            'code'      => 404,
            'message'   => 'El archivo no ha podido subirse'
        );
    }else{
        $result = array(
            'status'    => 'success',
            'code'      => 200,
            'message'   => 'El archivo se ha subido',
            'filename'  => $file_name
        );
    }
}
```

Intente cambiando la linea 7:
Esta:

```
array("image/jpeg","image/png","image/gif")
```

Por esta

```
array("*")
```

Para intentar que admitiera todos los archivos, si es que ese es el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu array agrega los siguientes valores `'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed'`, siguiendo tu ejemplo con esto le estarias indicando que también te permita realizar el upload de archivos tipo `.zip`.

Espero te sirva.